# Prevent website copy

Tags: javascript, security, nginx

Some domains are copying/scrapping my site's content and displaying on their domain. I checked the source code and found they are removing all Javascript tags so I am unable to use Javascript to redirect.

in nginx I have prohibited hot linking of images/css etc.

How can I prevent those domains to display my site content? They are completely copying my site, just like an iframe does.

Comment: which site is it?

Comment: Can you blacklist the domains completely in nginx?

Comment: @ webdeb I can't display domain publicly for privacy. @ Ali Somay I have blocked the domain and IP but I want to protect this behavior for future, I can't monitor always which domain is using my content.

Answer (score -1):

If you know what websites are stealing your content then something like this might work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.referrer.indexOf("websitescrapingyoursite.com") != -1) {
        window.location = "http://www.zombo.com";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: bots are not using javascript

Comment: The question asker **specifically** stated that the bots are stripping JavaScript, so he cannot use JavaScript to deal with the bots. Please actually fully read the question before providing an answer.

Comment: Ah, well I don't understand how they could be scraping his site like an iFrame and have it be fully functional without including the JavaScript... If that is the case then try including some JavaScript that when not included breaks the site.